# Visual Studio 2019: C# Version

Tags: c#

I just recently started back into C# and installed Visual Studio 2019 on APRIL 14,2021.

I started a new .NET Core Windows Forms App targeting Core Framework 4.7.2

I was starting to do some work with basic database connections:

I used the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;


In my Form_1 Load section:


using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(AMZN_select, AMZN_Connection);
```

I get an error:

"Feature 'usings declarations' is not available in C#7.3. Please use language 8.0 or greater"

So my question: I installed this version a few days ago in 2021. We are on version 9.0 I think for C#. I was assuming that a new project in 2021 would automatically taregt at least C#8, not C#7.3.

When I search the Google machine for this error I see people editing configuration files? Seriously?
Thats how you target the correct C# version in a completely new project?
I am willing to start from scratch and restart the project and open a new project but can I target the LATEST available C# version from the creation of the project. Again, I thought targeting a 4.xx framework would automatically get me C# version 8.0

What am I missing.

If I have to edit a config file can someone tell me what file I have to edit. I just can't believe the IDE allows me to create a project, get started and then tell me I am not targeting a current version of C#.

Again, I am returning to Visual Studio after 5 years but I don't remember having this issue back then.

OK heres what I found:

When I created the app I used:

[image]

Apparently you have to use:

[image]

I read the descriptions of the two and they seem virtually identical but apparently not.

One allows me to use:

'using'

**UPDATE:**

[image]

So the choice is grayed out depending on how you began the project.

Comment: Yeah OK, I understand your solution but that depends on What you search for in Google. It doesn't address the above.

Comment: See screenshot above. Why is language version grayed out? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version The latest C# compiler determines a default language version based on your project's target framework or frameworks. Visual Studio doesn't provide a UI to change the value, but you can change it by editing the csproj file.

Comment: Sorry I'm on VS2017. Looks like you're not the only one to complain see https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/16335 and https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/pull/4923 see also https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/main/docs/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version.md

Answer (score 1):

C# 7.3 is the last C# version targeting .NET Framework. Newer language versions are only available for .NET Core 3, .NET 5 or .NET Standard 2.1.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/configure-language-version .